# Implementar Undo y Redo en un EditText en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Por más que busco, el componente `EditText` no integra un sistema de Deshacer cambios, me gustaría implementar un sistema `Undo/Redo` es decir `Deshacer/Rehacer`

¿O bien conocéis un componente que derive de `EditText` de Android pero que tenga sistema de `Undo/Redo` o solo `Undo`?

**Update**
Algo he encontrado por [Github](https://gist.github.com/kidinov/6900164) sobre el tema.

Pero no entiendo como se implementa, necesito un ejemplo básico

Comment: Acabo de encontrar eso https://gist.github.com/kidinov/6900164

Comment: Otro elemento que puede servir https://github.com/qinci/AndroidEdit

Answer (score 0):

Según esta respuesta de  [SO:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808701/how-to-apply-undo-and-redo-operation-to-edittext-on-button-click-in-android)

Haces uso de los métodos de la clase en el listener de un botón por ejemplo.

```
  LaClaseQueEncontrasteEnGitHub mTextViewUndoRedo = new LaClaseQueEncontrasteEnGitHub (edtNoteDescription);

BotonUndo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
    }
});


if (mmPosition == 0) { 
     return null;
 }
```

Igual puedes revisar esa respuesta para que veas todos los comentarios de esa pregunta.